# Value of the manometric pressure

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure

I need to know the pressure acting on the left side of the surface in this picture.

And the answer is that $p_{M0} = \rho*g*h$ and the $\rho$ in that equation is equal to the $\rho$ of the fluid on the right side of the surface.

But clearly the fluid on the left side is a gas and doesn't have the same density as the fluid on the right side (presumably water).

Somehow the technique is (I guess) to calculate the hydrostatic pressure of that gas at some depth (we can choose the depth of the free surface, the surface on which the atmospheric pressure acts, namely the pressure $Pa$) and than we obtain that $p_{M0} = \rho*g*h$.

But I don't know how that makes sense. Can someone explain how can we get the value of $p_{M0} $?
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: imagine the centre line C- - D then balance both sides

Comment: I don't quite understand, could you expand a little bit more please?

Comment: so do an equation like you have for the left side, for the right hand side.

Comment: I did that, there are 2 forces acting, one on the slanted surface acting from the surface onto the fluid, namely $F_{h1}=sqrt2/2*\rho*g*h^2*B$ and the other one acting on the vertical surface $F_{h2}= \rho*g*h^2*B$. And I understand how to do that on the right side of the surface. Just simple hydrostatic pressure that grows linearly, but my question was how do I know that the manometric pressure on the left side is that what it is? It is not given and I don't know how to get to that equation which I used to calculate the left hand side.

Comment: the pressure of the liquid will be a gradient with depth.  The pressure of the gas won't be.  Calc the liq pressure based on an average, then determine hte gas pressure that provides the equal force.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your comments.